# invariants of semilinear transformation under change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, linear-transformations

In usual linear algebra (over a field or ring), matrices have several invariants (some more 'numerical' than others) under change of basis - e.g. trace, determinant, eigenvalues - many of these encompassed in the characteristic polynomial.

Consider now a semilinear map over a ring $R$ with a ring automorphism $\sigma:R\to R$. (feel free to assume $\sigma$ is the Frobenius and $R$ is a perfect ring).

Given an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, change of basis by an element $P$ of $\mathbf{GL}_n(R)$ acts as $PA(\sigma(P))^{-1}$, where $\sigma(P)$ is obtained by applying $\sigma$ to every entry of $P$; i.e. by $\sigma$-twisted conjugation.

*What* 'things' remain invariant? It doesn't seem to make sense to talk about the characteristic polynomial or eigenvalues, but certainly some things do stay invariant such as kernel, rank (whenever defined). I think one *can* talk about eigenvectors but not eigenvalues!

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you ask for migration to MathOF? (or repost on MathOF, mentioning or deleting the original here)